# Two dropdowns filled dynamically from mysql

Tags: jquery, html

I have a dropdown that is filled by a database mysql and everything runs well. Then I have a second dropdown that is filled also by a database upon the selection from the first dropdown. 
Two problems:

1. The first item from dropdown 1 doesn't fill dropdown
2. If I select
   an item from dropdown 1, it gives me the items to dropdown 2, of the
   last item in dropdown 1.

Can someone help?1
This is my code:

```
<select id="categoria" onChange="selectServ()">
<option value="item" class="itemoption">Categoria</option>
</select>

<select id="servicos">
<option value="item" class="itemoption">Serviço</option>

</select>
<script>
$(function(){

  var items="";
  $.getJSON("http://example.com/servicos_categorias.php",function(data){

    $.each(data,function(index,item) 
    {
      items+="<option value='"+item.ID+"'>"+item.categoria+"</option>";
    });
    $("#categoria").html(items); 
  });
});

</script>
<script>
function selectServ(){
    var e = document.getElementById("categoria");
    var servSelected = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;

    var url = "";

  var items="";
  if(servSelect = 1){
  url = "http://example.com/servicos_threading.php";
  }
  if(servSelect = 2){
  url = "http://example.com/servicos_sobrancelhas.php";
  }
  if(servSelect = 3){
  url = "http://example.com/servicos_manicure.php";
  }
  $.getJSON(url,function(data){

    $.each(data,function(index,item) 
    {
      items+="<option value='"+item.ID+"'>"+item.servico+"</option>";
    });
    $("#servicos").html(items); 
  });
};

</script>
```

tried also to use this:

```
    if(servSelect = 1){
  url = "http://example.com/servicos_threading.php";
  }
  else if(servSelect = 2){
  url = "http://example.com/servicos_sobrancelhas.php";
  }
  else if(servSelect = 3){
  url = "http://example.com/servicos_manicure.php";
  }
```

But then it doesn't fill both drop downs.

Answer (score 0):

I see at least one problem and possibly two problems in your javascript,

you are using a single equal-sign which means assignment, not comparison.
the second issue is that servSelect will most likely be a string

```
if(servSelect = 1){
```

should be:

```
if(servSelect === '1') {
```

Comment: Doesn't fill dropdown 2 with anything at all.

Comment: I'm sorry, there was a mispeled issue. Should be if (servSelected), and it does't mater if it "= 1" or "==="1"". But it has to be like @Mukul Khatter sugested. The problem now is wit issue #1. Item 1 in dropdown 1, doesn't fill dropdown 2.

Answer (score 0):

i think you have call function like this if calling javascript function

onChange="return selectServ()"

Comment: Now it fills all items in dropdown 2 with which is selected on dropdown 1 item #2 :S

Comment: I'm sorry there was a mispelled issue. Instead of serSelect, should be servSelected. Now the only issue is that item 1 in dropdown 1 doesn't fill dropdown 2.